# Error if the Activity is having getActionbar(), when I am implementing TextInputLayout in one of Layout in android

Tags: android, material-design

This is my first activity loaded at every time when I run the app. 
 MainActivity

```
public class UpdateFile extends ListActivity {

//my navigationdrawer code goes here..

oncreate method(){
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 }
  some code goes here//
 }

}
```

My floating layout floating.xml file is here

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
 android:id="@+id/NameLayout"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/editname"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
 android:ems="10"
 android:hint="Name"/>
 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

FloatingClass

```
 FloatingClass extends Activity
{
 onCreate()
 setContentView(R.layout.floating);

}
```

Finally in the gradle file dependency has been setted to 
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1(whatever appcompat version is having)

I am getting this error, Can anyone guide me how to solve this issue.

```
  Process: com.project.app, PID: 8997                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.project.app/com.letzkit.casenotez.update}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at com.project.app.update.onCreate(update.java:323)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check for the theme of the activity it should not be '...NoActionBar' theme.

Comment: @mithil1501 , I have not mentioned NoActionBar in my theme.

Comment: but one thing , if i delete compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1 from the gradle and TextInputLayout, every thing works well.

Comment: I am not sure but I guess for 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1' you might need support actionbar from appcompat lib. So, I will suggest use AppCompatActivity from support lib v7, So, that you can use 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1' freely and then in this Activity you can add ListFragment.

Comment: you mean this right compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0', I have already added. but not working.

Comment: Actually you should use AppCompatActivity as base activity instead ListActivity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130484/discussion-between-kogile-and-mithil1501).

Answer (score 0):

Use AppCompatActivity instead of ListActivity like -

```
public class UpdateFile extends AppCompatActivity
```

instead of

```
public class UpdateFile extends ListActivity
```

You should add AppCompatActivity to your app by adding the following dependency in app level Gradle file -

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1
```